# Web Essential minifying LESS files generates wrong content when contains \

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less, minify, web-essentials

I have a LESS file in Visual Studio that contains this:

```
.someclass {
    content: "\f005";
}
```

It works fine and gives the same result when compiles the the corresponding .css file, but when I check the genereated .min.css file i get this:

```
.someclass:{content:""}
```

There seems to be some kind of encoding error.
I have Visual Studio Premium 2013, version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4. Web Essentials for Update 4